# creating an email capture landing page

Tags: html, email, capture, mailchimp

What is the best way to go about having an email capture landing page?
My has a wordpress site, and wants to integrate an email capturing landing page like fab.com has. The client would like to use Mailchimp to maintain their list, if that matters.

I guess specifically, I'd like to know how to ensure the names and emails entered into the input fields will be saved by Mailchimp.

Any and all advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean, maybe you're looking for a newsletter sign up plugin that supports MailChimp?

Check Here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/newsletter-sign-up/

Comment: I'm looking for that functionality, but not a plugin so I can style it according to the clients specifications

Comment: From the plugin readme:

"Customizable
All generated forms come with common CSS classes and unique CSS identifiers so that you can easily style them to your likings."